# How to find optimal noise covariance matrices Q & R

Tags: kalman

I am trying to use the discrete Kalman filter for forecasting and I wonder what is commonly considered as the optimal way of determining the measurement noise covariance constants (Q and R) for a given time series? Do you recommend some approaches based on your research/experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently blogged about this very topic.

Essentially, there are 3 ways to estimate Q & R.

1. approximate

   - calculate variate estimate of error in a controlled environment
   - if z doesn't change, calculate variance estimate of z
   - if z does change, calculate variance of regression estimate of z
2. guess

   - use some constant multiplied by the identity matrix
   - higher the constant, higher the noise
3. MLE

   - pykalman's [em](https://pykalman.github.io/#optimizing-parameters)
   - unfortunately, non-convex problem => local optima

Check out the rest of my post [here](http://alphamaximus.com/kalman/statistics/python/2015/08/21/kalman-filters.html)